# Bootstrap columns are overlapping and aligning left for custom columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, grid

```css
.col-sm-1-5 {
  flex: 0 0 12.5%;
  max-width: 12.5%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: right">myInput1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1-5" style="text-align: right">myInput2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: right">myInput3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: right">myInput4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: right">myInput5</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1-5" style="text-align: right">myInput6</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: right">myInput7</div>              
    <div class="col-sm-1-5" style="text-align: right">myInput8</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1-5" style="text-align: right">myInput9</div>
</div>
```

I need to align the custom column added in my css style, but even though I have given `text:align: right` some of my custom columns (`col-sm-1-5`) still aligns left. i.e., myInput2, myInput6, myInput8....

Comment: If you want to align all div elements to the right so why are you using custom class for other elements if you simply remove your css for custom class (col-sm-1-5) then all elements will be right align.